# Shell script not picking up password file...

Tags: shell, passwords, gnupg, pgp

Running the below shell script seems to ignore the password file I'm feeding it.  I'm continually prompted for it.  If I enter it, the rest of the script goes without a hitch, but as I'm running it via cron, I really need to get it to read from the file... Any suggestions?

```
#!/bin/sh
p=$(<password.txt)
set -- $p
pass_phrase=$1
destination="/var/www/d"
cd /var/sl/
for FILE in *.pgp;
do
    FILENAME=${FILE%.pgp}
    gpg --passphrase "$pass_phrase" --output "$destination/$FILENAME" --decrypt "$FILE"
    rm -f $FILE
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies in line 2:

```
p=$(<password.txt)
```

What you are doing here is to run an "empty command" in a subshell, storing its output in the variable `p`. What you rather want to do though, is to run a command that outputs the contents of the password file to `stdout`. So:

```
p=$(cat <password.txt)
```

This will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to specify a full path to the file.  Or in your cron job, first cd to the directory containing that file.

Answer (score 0):

Does `--passphrase` really exist? According to [the manpage](http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manpage.en.html) it doesn't, but the versions might be different.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the password file? `cron` has a different `PATH`, which can cause scripts to behave differently when you run them yourself.

Possible solution one, put

```
cd `dirname $0`
```

at the top of the script, which would `cd` into the script's directory when it runs.

Possible solution two, try specifying the file directly with an absolute path:

```
gpg --passphrase-file /some/path/password.txt -o "$destination/$FILENAME" -d "$FILE"
```